# URL partially encode

Tags: python, url

I am reading an API documentation and they say the format should be like:

```
https://app.datafireball.com/SearchService/search/xref?parts=[{"partNumber":"mypartnumber", "manufacturer":"my factory"}]&fmt=xml
```

And when I monitor in chrome developer console. the requested url looks like:

```
https://app.datafireball.com/SearchService/search/xref?parts=[{%22partNumber%22:%22bav99%22,%22manufacturer%22:%22my%20factory%22}]&fmt=xml
```

I can see that there are several characters that have been encoded, for example:

```
" => %22
space => %20
```

I know that I can use `urllib.quote` to make that happen, however, I am really having a hard time understanding why they are only encoding double quotes and space instead of the `{` curly brackets and other characters.

In the end, I have to hard code my Python code in a way like this:

```
urltemplate = "https://app.datafireball.com/SearchService/search/xref?parts=[{{%22partNumber%22:%22{0}%22,%22manufacturer%22:%22{1}%22}}]&fmt=xml"
url = urltemplate.format(urllib.quote(mpn), urllib.quote(mfr))
```

which looks half-hard coded, can anyone help me understand why and what is the proper way to encode the url.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need to do the encode work yourself, the brower who encode your url to different format will also decode your url back when call server API.